# Get only date from time/date in query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to fill a combobox in my access form with dates from an existing table. But I only want to get the dates (without time) and I only want to have each date once (distinct).
The convert method does not work and an error occurs. And I want this format: `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Thank you so much!

Find my current SQL code below which I want to alter to the correct query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table33.CREATED
FROM table33;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access use `Format`, For more info please see this [LINK](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php).

I added `order by` clause at the end since you want to bind this data into combobox so it should be in one proper order.

```
select format(table33.CREATED, "dd-mm-yyyy") from table33 order by table33.CREATED ;
```

For SQL Server

Use `convert`. Use style `105` for your format. You may find the list of styles and info about the same from this [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT( VARCHAR, table33.CREATED, 105 ) as Created
FROM table33;
```

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I've tried. But Access told me: " undefined function 'CONVERT' in expression " . What did I wrong? Thanks for the fast answer :)

Comment: @Luke: use `Format` in MS Access

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FORMAT()` in MS Access:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT(table33.CREATED, "dd-mm-yyyy")
FROM table33;
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a date without a time component **whilst retaining the data in a datetime data type** (rather than converting the data to a string as you would using the [`Format`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-function-6f29d87b-8761-408d-81d3-63b9cd842530) function), you can use the [`DateValue`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-03878f08-b0db-42df-8a0c-279939637c6f) function, e.g.:

```
select distinct datevalue(table33.created) from table33
```

Then, apply any necessary formatting using the [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.format) property of the combobox itself.

This way, you can still filter & manipulate the data as a date.